# Slicing a 2-dimensional array

Tags: php

Error tells me that: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
   $vendorlist = array(array($n,$ca,$b,$co,$a,$aa,$aaa,$t,$tt,$e,$p));
   $record = unserialize(@file_get_contents('./Vendors/$vendorlist'));

   $new_vendor_number = array_slice($record[0],-1,5);
   $catname = array_slice($record[0],5,100);

        echo "$new_vendor_number";
        echo "$catname";

   $new_vendor_number = array_slice($record[1],-1,5);
   $catname = array_slice($record[1],5,100);

        echo "$new_vendor_number";
        echo "$catname";

   ?>
```

Comment: Is `$record[0]` an array ? Try `var_dump($record)` and make sure about the data it contains.

Comment: remove @ sign before `file_get_contents` and You may find a reason.